# amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition not creating service - Error : "Service is INACTIVE"

Tags: amazon-web-services, ecs-taskdefinition

I'm trying to deploy a dotnet service to a cluster in ECS using a git action on a pull request.

Everything works fine up to the aws-actions/amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition@v1 step which fails giving an error of "Service is INACTIVE".

In this case there is no running service attached to the task definition.  If I create the service manually it runs fine and any subsequent deployments work, but if the service has been deleted the amazon-ecs-deploy-task-definition step appears unable to recreate the service and start it.

Any idea how I can force it to create the service and start it?

Comment: "if the service has been deleted" -> Why is it deleted?

If your action trigger is on CodePipeline, you can deploy a Cloudformation template to create the service and start it.

Comment: It had been deleted when it was misbehaving.  I'll look into that, thanks.